# rsync variables script syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

Really struggling with getting a command argument variable to work with rsync. The behavior i'm seeing is this error from the script:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
```

However the script outputs the command it's going to run via an echo, and the exact same command copy pasted into the terminal (or back into the script as the first line with a exit after it) works just fine ?!

Script code that does this rsync (check_flags is empty in this case):

```
rsync_cmd=(${check_flags} -rWltpgoDvdHP --delete-before -- \"${backup_dir}\" \"admin@nas-1:${backup_basename}/\")

echo "CMD to run: rsync ${rsync_cmd[@]}"

rsync ${rsync_cmd[@]}
```

Output:

```
CMD to run: rsync -rWltpgoDvdHP --delete-before -- "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/veeam_backup_daily/Daily backup _@1am__1" "admin@nas-1:/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/veeam_backup_daily/"
```

I've read online that using an array should help this issue, but it didn't in this case. I'm fairly sure this is an easy fix but it's driving me nuts !

Comment: `the exact same command copy pasted into the terminal[...]works just fine ` So, in that case, from where comes your variables ?

Comment: i mean the output of the echo, pasted back into a terminal as a command. It seems like eval might be able to 'fix' the issue, but i'm not sure why that'd make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell parses quotes before it substitutes variables, so including quotes in the variable's value doesn't do what you expect (and the `echo` is highly misleading because it doesn't show this distinction). What you should do is use unescaped quotes when defining the array (so they're parsed as delimiters around array elements, rather than part of the array value), then double-quote the reference to the array (so it doesn't word-split or wildcard-expand the values in the array). I'd also replace the `echo` command with a `printf` that'll show what's going to happen more accurately:

```
rsync_cmd=(${check_flags} -rWltpgoDvdHP --delete-before -- "${backup_dir}" "admin@nas-1:${backup_basename}/")

printf "%q " CMD to run: rsync "${rsync_cmd[@]}"
printf "\n"

rsync "${rsync_cmd[@]}"
```

Note that the `printf` may not show what you expect -- it'll print an *equivalent* representation of the command that'll be executed, but there are many different equivalent representations of each argument, and it'll pick one based on its preferences, not how it was originally entered. BTW, you can also use `set -x` to debug things like this, but (as with `printf "%q "`) it may use a different representation than you expect.