# Baffled by rsync filters in shell variables

Tags: bash, rsync

I am baffled by rync filters, they seem to be specially designed to interact in the most confusing possible way with bash shell expressions. For example,

```
FILTERS="-f'- *.mov'"
```

gets expanded to `'-f'\''- *.mov'\'''`
which yields Unknown filter rule: '- *.mov''

```
FILTERS="-f\'- \*.mov\'"
```

gets expanded to `'-f\'\''- \*.mov\'\'''`
with the same result

etc

If you just type `rsync ... -f'- *.mov'` on the command line the filter works as intended.

Is there any sane way to pass a filter expression to rsync? Just looking to exclude all *mov files from the rsync.

Comment: This isn't a problem with `rsync`, it's a problem with storing shell syntax (e.g. quotes and escapes) in variables -- it doesn't work, because the shell parses those things *before* expanding variables. To store complex arguments, use an array rather than a plain variable (see ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948) and [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). BTW, the `'\''` is an artifact of `set -x`.

Comment: Aha thanks for catching that I was using set -x, and to the post you refer to explaining why arrays are better then "eval". 

I solved the problem another way, with an exclude file.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: ["rsync variables script syntax error"](https://superuser.com/questions/920977/rsync-variables-script-syntax-error).

Answer (score 0):

If `-f'- *.mov'` works correctly, the following should work also:

```
FILTERS='-f- *.mov'
rsync ... "$FILTERS"
```

The shell removes the single quotes from the working expression, but they prevent the word splitting on the space, and the expansion of the wildcard.
Double quoting the variable achieves the same.

Comment: Nope, rsync expects a ' after the -f and at the end of the expression: 

`FILTERS='-f- *mov'``

`rsync -avRlh --dry-run --verbose --delete --delete-excluded --no-links -f- '*mov' MyMovies MyPictures MyPictures4 MyPicturesThumbs /tmp`

`unexpected end of filter rule: -`

Comment: @wsanders: The shell removes the single quote if it's not escaped or double quoted. The command never sees the single quote.

Comment: In shell syntax, passing an argument (directly in the command, not via a variable) as `-f'- *.mov'` is identical to passing it as `'-f- *.mov'` or `-f-' *'.mov` or `-f-\ \*.mov` or `"-f- *.mov"` or any of many other combos. The only thing that matters is that the space and asterisk be quoted or escaped to suppress their normal syntactic meaning; the rest of the characters in the argument don't have any special syntactic meaning to suppress, so quoting them doesn't have any effect vs leaving them unquoted. And in all these cases, the shell removes the quotes/escapes before passing them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I gave up and used a rsync exclude file. This works and is much less baffling:

Create a file called $HOME/.rsync-filter with the contents: `- *.mov`

You can use a shell variable: `FILTERS="merge $HOME/.rsync-filter"`

Then this command: `rsync -avRlh --delete --delete-excluded --no-links -f="$FILTERS" $FOLDERS /mnt/something`

You could put the exclude file in the shell script as a here file if you wanted to.